# Fail load test when individual test cases fail

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I've implemented load test suite using MSTest test cases with Visual Studio 2015. I can execute the load test fine but I'd like to fail the load test run if there are any test failures. Now I get a green success symbol with text "Test run completed  Results 1/1 passed" and I have to dig deeper into load test report to notice that actually some or even all test cases failed.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**

I was too vague in describing my setup. To clarify there are:

- Separate test project with MSTest classes (decorated with TestClass attributes) which are implemented so that they can self-host the WCF service or they can use WCF service from some server,
- a Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test Project and
- a load test file (.loadtest) which uses MSTest classes.

I understand that typically load tests use Web Performance Tests (.webtest) which can be recorded using a browser. I opted to use MSTest tests instead because the system under test is a WCF service and not a web page so tests would be hard to create as I couldn't use browser recording.

I have this setup up and running and I can see how my system under test performs. Only problem is that if some these MSTest executions fail (e.g. Assert.AreEqual fails), I can see the errors when I read detailed test report but if one just quickly glances at the report and sees "Test run completed Results 1/1 passed", they might think that performance test was a success even though at least some or even all MSTest executions failed.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a web test can be set to pass or fail in code, eg

```
public class xxx : WebTestPlugin // also based on WebTestRequestPlugin

{
    public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult("Outcome was " + e.WebTest.Outcome.ToString());
        e.WebTest.Outcome = Outcome.Fail; // to force a failure
    }
}
```

I have not found a way of setting the outcome for an entire load test. The outcome for the individual tests is accumulated.

Comment: My test cases are implemented using MSTest and are not aware of Load Test libraries. I'd like to keep them that way as I also use them in regular automated test runs along with unit tests. Automated test runs use self hosted service as the target whereas during load tests I use an installed version of the server software.

Comment: @VilleSalonen Lets clarify. What do you mean by "load testing"? Are you using a Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test project, as per  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/06/04/getting-started-with-load-testing-in-visual-studio-2012/  ?